Masking Policies & dynamic tables in snowflake
I'm working with Dynamic Tables in Snowflake and trying to apply masking policies to hide sensitive data. However, when I create the dynamic table, I get the following error:
The masking policies are using current_user() and current_role() and are sort to the tables used in the dynamic table..
Error: context function

I would like to know:

Is it possible to use masking policies with Dynamic Tables in Snowflake in incremental mode?
How can I resolve the "context function" error?

I tried to use a masking policy with a context function

Yes, you can create masking policies on a dynamic table. Please update your question to show the DDL for the masking policy and the DDL for how you are applying it to a column in a table
